# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, navigation

I am looping through products and extracting some information and in loop i am also clicking on the product to go to Product Detail page (PDP). After that i am extracting brand information and want to go back to the previous page. but after using the driver.goback() the loop does not work.from selenium import webdriver

```
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
import time
PATH = r"C:\Users\MaxPain\Documents\geckodriver.exe"

ser = Service(PATH_C)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)

# driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000)")
MainURL = "https://www.amazon.com/s?i=electronics-intl-ship&bbn=16225009011&rh=n%3A2811119011%2Cn%3A2407755011&dc&ds=v1%3AC0LTQbPEHkj0izU%2BGQ%2FVcuqm26QN2oitQYzfpo09qvk&qid=1663587128&rnid=2811119011&ref=sr_nr_n_2"
driver.get(MainURL)

mainloop = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , '//div[@data-component-type="s-search-result"]')
print("Total Products : " , len(mainloop))
data = []
for index, l in enumerate(mainloop):

    title = l.find_element(By.XPATH ,'.//h2/a/span').text
    URL = l.find_element(By.XPATH, './/h2/a').get_attribute('href')
    l.find_element(By.XPATH, './/h2/a').click()
    brand = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@id = "bylineInfo"]').text.replace("Visit the ","")
    # brand = brand.replace("Store","").trim()
    # print(brand)
    data.append({'TItle':title,"ProductURL":URL, "Brand":brand})
    driver.back()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('AmzTest.csv')
```

But using this code i am getting this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00CDDF13+2219795]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C72841+1779777]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B8423D+803389]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B86D04+814340]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B86BC2+814018]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B86E50+814672]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BB2D4F+994639]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BB31EB+995819]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA9531+955697]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BCE844+1108036]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA94B4+955572]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BCEA14+1108500]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BDF192+1175954]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BCE616+1107478]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA7F89+950153]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA8F56+954198]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FD2CB2+3040210]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FC2BB4+2974420]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D76A0A+565546]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D75680+560544]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C79A5C+1808988]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C7E3A8+1827752]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C7E495+1827989]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C880A4+1867940]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76DD7BA9+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x777CBB3B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x777CBABF+191]
```

Is there any way to resolve this problem.

I know i can extract all the urls once and create another robot to extract PDP information. But the purpose of this is more to learn about how i can navigate over different pages.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'create another robot'. Once you navigate to a different page and then back, you need to redefine the elements (including the products list) and make sure you click on the next one, which would imply incrementing the index... it's a mess really. Just define the products links, then loop through them one by one. You'll be alright, you're a ScraperMaster, no?

Answer (score 0):

When you going to another page with this line `l.find_element(By.XPATH, './/h2/a').click()` all the web elements initially collected in `mainloop` list are becoming stale. In Selenium Web Element is actually a reference to a physical web element. When you coming back to the main page it is re-rendered so the previously collected references to web elements no more pointing to those elements.
To make your code working you need to collect the `mainloop` list again when getting back to the main page.
The following code works:

```py
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?i=electronics-intl-ship&bbn=16225009011&rh=n%3A2811119011%2Cn%3A2407755011&dc&ds=v1%3AC0LTQbPEHkj0izU%2BGQ%2FVcuqm26QN2oitQYzfpo09qvk&qid=1663587128&rnid=2811119011&ref=sr_nr_n_2'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-component-type="s-search-result"]')))
mainloop = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-component-type="s-search-result"]')
print("Total Products : " , len(mainloop))
data = []
for index, l in enumerate(mainloop):
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-component-type="s-search-result"]')))
    mainloop = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-component-type="s-search-result"]')
    l = mainloop[index]
    title = l.find_element(By.XPATH, './/h2/a/span').text
    URL = l.find_element(By.XPATH, './/h2/a').get_attribute('href')
    l.find_element(By.XPATH, './/h2/a').click()
    brand = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@id = "bylineInfo"]').text.replace("Visit the ","")
    data.append({'TItle':title,"ProductURL":URL, "Brand":brand})
    driver.back()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('AmzTest.csv')
```